# Picking a torrent application for a server

Tags: server, software-recommendation, bittorrent

I'd like to configure my headless Ubuntu server (64bit) to download and seed torrent files. I'm looking for an application with the following requirements (in order of importance):

1. Easily work with OpenVPN
2. Let me select individual files in a torrent.
3. Good command line interface
4. A web ui to connect to from the local network.
5. Ease of setup

I've been looking at these forums and it seems rtorrent, deluge, and transmission are the most popular and all three seem to support the above. Is this correct?

What about the alpha version of the utorrent?

Any general tips about diving into this?

Thanks for your input!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

OpenVPN should be transparent to the application, so it should work regardless of which client you choose.

Personally I use transmission(-daemon). It has a well written interface with both web, stateless command line and ncurses command line interfaces. It is also very easy to set up.

It works great for me at least ;)

Comment: +1 for `transmission`. Very versatile.

Comment: Thanks! And transmission does allow you to select specific files from a torrent, correct?

Comment: Yes it does indeed.

Comment: @Evan - yes it does.

Comment: Another note with Transmission: you can use the Qt desktop client as a frontend to the server. Once you set it up, it looks just like you're running Transmission on your desktop, except that it's controlling the daemon on the server. Really slick.

Comment: @Ryan Thompson Nice, I didn't know about that. A really neat feature indeed!

Answer (score 2):

[Torrentflux](http://prdownloads.sourceforge.net/torrentflux/torrentflux_2.1.tar.gz?download) should do what you need, I've had a play with uTorrent and it isn't there yet.

Haven't heard of the other ones.

Comment: I've use TorrentFlux before. It's has a quite comprehensive feature set, but I recall it being harder to set up than transmission-daemon.

Answer (score 2):

[rTorrent](http://libtorrent.rakshasa.no/) sounds like it meets all your requirements (perhaps a bit lacking on the ease of setup, but well worth the trouble.) It's available in the repos but if you want a web GUI you'll need to compile it yourself with XMLRPC support. The wiki for [ruTorrent](http://code.google.com/p/rutorrent/) has a good guide on how to compile rTorrent and make it ready for ruTorrent's web GUI.

[image: rTorrent's nCurses interface]
[image: ruTorrent's Web GUI]

Answer (score 1):

**torrentflux**

web based, feature-rich BitTorrent download managerTorrentFlux is a PHP based BitTorrent controller that runs on a web server. It can manage all of your BitTorrent downloads from anywhere through a convenient and easy-to-use web interface. TorrentFlux uses a MySQL database to manage the downloads. This database may be automatically created and maintained for you (if you want), but that requires the recommended mysql-client package. If you do not have a remote database server to access, you will also need the recommended mysql-server package. (If you’re not sure, then you probably need both.)
TorrentFlux enables you to run BitTorrent downloads unattended on a monitor-less or remote server 24 hours a day, while still maintaining complete control from any web browser. Now you can control your downloading on your firewall, or keep up with downloads while on vacation. It uses the BitTornado client to download files, and also requires a web server with PHP.
Some of the many features:

- Upload Torrents via URL or File Upload
- Start, Stop, and Delete Torrents with ease
- Advanced Torrent start options (ports, speeds, etc.)
- Multi-user interface
- RSS Feeds, download Torrents files with a click
- Run several torrents at once
- View Download Progress of all torrents at a glance
- View drive space at a glance
- View Torrent file meta information
- Built-in User management and Security
- Private Messaging
- Themes (selectable per user)
- Upload History
- Detailed User Administration
- Admin Searchable Logs
- Torrent Search (many popular sites)
- Language Support
- Make your own torrents
- Add torrents to a download Queue
- NFO / Text viewer

*Install torrentflux in Ubuntu*

> sudo aptitude install torrentflux

Answer (score 0):

you should try [utorrent](http://utorrent.com) using wine and why not the alpha linux version.
Us

Comment: Using wine + μTorrent on a server really sounds sub par when there are good working native alternatives. Hell I wouldn't even advice it for your home setup.

Comment: +1 for this being a bad idea. Ignoring the fact that the original question is regarding a server: [Transmission](http://www.transmissionbt.com/) comes pre-installed with Ubuntu (Desktop), and there are [many reasons](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%CE%9CTorrent#Revenue) why it would be preferable to running μTorrent via some sort of compatibility layer *especially* as the intention is _reliable_ service!